# Exchange 2010 Pop/Smtp Connection

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, hosted-exchange

I am serving hosted Exchange 2010 to my clients. One of my client came with how to use Outlook Express and Windows 7 Mail with Exchange.

I have made researches, read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124107(v=exchg.141).aspx article and configured my server.

Unfortunatelly POP connection doesn't work. testexchangeconnectivity.com tool errors on ceritificate but nothing should be wrong with certificate or configuration.

Do you see a mistake?

I defined Client Access server as POP and Imap server and Hub Transport server for SMTP.

**Pop settings instructions on OWA** (4th Edit)
[image: Pop settings instructions on OWA]

**EMS pop settings details** (5th Edit)
[image]

**testexchangeconnectivity.com result**  (4th Edit)
[image: testexchange]

**get-exchangecertificate** (1st Post)
[image: **get-exchangecertificate**]

**get-exchangecertificate | fl** after UC/SAN certificate installed (5th Edit)
[image]

**get-exchangecertificate | fl** after new certificate for pop service installed (4th Edit)
[image: get-exchangecertificate | fl]

**get-exchangecertificate | fl** before new certificate for pop service installed (1st Post)
[image: get-exchangecertificate]

Comment: Do you have your Exchange certificate assigned to POP? Run Get-ExchangeCertificate and the Services column should have a 'P' under it next to your public-facing Exchange certificate.

Comment: Yeah. I have P and W under Services

Comment: have you checked related ports are opened to internet? do you have a firewall? or maybe Windows Firewall?

Comment: Yes, no firewall. Not only opened the ports, also disabled the firewall.

Comment: I have read something about using different certificates for different services. Anyone knows something about it?

Comment: I assigned a new IP and a SSL for it. Also assigned new certificate for POP service. Nothing happened.

Comment: Two things:  1) follow this article - http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-publish-pop3-client-settings/ 2) Do an IISRESET.

Comment: I was going to suggest verifying your X509CertificateName field contains the FQDN from your cert as well.

Comment: @TheCleaner I actually read that article, too. And done the instructions.

Comment: @Jeremy Lyons I couldnt't find an error. Could you see something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution after weeks.

If you try to connect Exchange Pop service with a third party you should change LoginType @ PopSettings

```
Set-Popsettings -LoginType plaintextlogin
```

Don't forget to restart the pop3 service

Thanks busbar@experts-exchange

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue...the status for the POP3 cert is INVALID.

[image]

Apparently according to Comodo this is a known issue with Exchange 2010 using their "EssentialSSL" cert.

See here: http://forums.comodo.com/ssl-certificate/certificate-is-invalid-for-exchange-server-usage-t86252.0.html

> Exchange 2010 does not like the EssentialSSL hierarchy for some reason
>   whereas Exchange 2007 had no issue with it. We recommend that for
>   Exchange 2010 that customers use the Unified Communications
>   certificate from our InstantSSL.com page.

Comment: Oh my god! I actually ordered a UC/SAN SSL but it is still waiting for validation. Was trying EssentialSSL just for testing. Then I will update my post after getting my UC/SAN SSL. Thank you btw.

Comment: I just installed SAN certificate but problem still occurs.

Comment: Can you post the pics again of get-ExchangeCertificate ?

Comment: please search page for `after UC/SAN certificate installed`